Curl-Div equation with singular matrix
I want to solve the equation:
$$
\begin{cases}
\nabla \times (A \mathbf v)=f, \quad x\in \Omega \\ 
\operatorname{div}(\mathbf v)=0,
\end{cases}
$$
where $\Omega \subset\mathbb{R}^n$, is an open set, $A$ is a $n\times n$, with $n=2,3$ and $f$ is a smooth function.
Question: Assume that A is a singular matrix. What can we say about the well-posedness of such an equation? Are there any references about such a system? I appreciate any help you can provide.
$\textbf{Edited}$: the matrix $A$ for the original is defined as $A\mathbf{v}=F\times \mathbf{v}$ where $F$ is some constant vector field. What can we say about this particular case?

You make no mention of x other than to state that it is a member of . It would help me understand the question if you clearly distinguished between what is the unknown that you are trying to solve for, and what is given.

If A can be any singular matrix, it could be the zero matrix. In that case, there are no solutions if $f\neq 0$, and lots of solutions if $f=0$. In the general case, a clearly necessary condition for solutions to exist is ${\rm div},f=0$.

@DanielAsimov $A$ can be taken constant matrix, $\boldsymbol{f}(x)$ is given, $\mathbf{v}(x)$ is the unknown. $x$ is the variable.

@MichaelRenardy Thank you sir for the answer. If we assume that $\operatorname{div}(f)\neq 0$, in which space can we restrict the study to guarantee well-posedness? and with which boundary conditions? If no boundary conditions are assigned, then it is noticed that if $\mathbf{v}$ is a solution then $\mathbf{v}$+$\mathbf{h}$ is also a solution, where $\mathbf{h}\in \operatorname{ker}(A)$ ($A$ is constant).

the singular matrix will restrict the dimensionality of the solution; as a simple case, consider $n=3$, $A=\text{diagonal},(1,1,0)$, $f=(0,0,F)$, with $F$ a function of $x,y$ only; then the solution is of the form $v=(v_x,v_y,0)$ with $v_x,v_y$ a function of $x,y$ only.

Thank you fir all the answers. I've added some details in the question. "the matrix $A$ for the original is defined as $A\mathbf{v}=F\times \mathbf{v}$ where $F$ is some constant vector field. What can we say about this particular case?"

that case is answered at https://mathoverflow.net/a/481828/11260
